# Reading data line by line in Java from the input stream

Tags: java, datainputstream

I need to read data of the format:
    2
    4
    7
    6 4
    2 5 10
    9 8 12 2

the data needs to be from the default input stream, System.in. I'm using an InputStreamReader wrapped in a BufferedReader, so I am able to do line by line reading.

```
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(isr);
    String x=in.readLine();
    int numcase=Integer.parseInt(x);
    for(int i=1;i<=numcase;i++){
        System.out.println("");
        x=in.readLine();
        int n=Integer.parseInt(x);
        int[][]t=new int[n+1][n+1];
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            System.out.println();
            x=in.readLine();
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(x);
            for(int k=1;k<=1;k++){
                x=st.nextToken();
                int nume=Integer.parseInt(x);
                t[j][k]=nume;
            }
        }
```

the problem is that if the blank System.out.println statement isnt there, it refuses to read in a line of input past reading the first two lines. Thing is, where I'm submitting the code monitors the output stream and as such will grade my output as incorrect by outputting the wrong answer.

Comment: Why not just use a `Scanner`, the normal way to read delimited input?

Comment: Yes, using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object and then using `myScanner.nextInt()` to get the next integer is a much easier method

Comment: input is fed via the input stream line by line, not number by number, otherwise Scanner would be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are expecting but writing to system.out has no effect on what you read from system.in.

That said some pointers about your code:

```
 String x=in.readLine();
 int numcase=Integer.parseInt(x);
 for(int i=1;i<=numcase;i++){
```

this loop will be entered twice.

```
x=in.readLine();
int n=Integer.parseInt(x);
int[][]t=new int[n+1][n+1];
```

n will be 4 and the array will be of size 5 by 5. Why? I cant understand the reasoning behind this.

```
 for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
```

this loop will be executed 4 times. Reading one line every time.

```
 StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(x);
        for(int k=1;k<=1;k++){
```

This loop will always be entered only **ONCE** even though there may be more than one token.

```
int nume=Integer.parseInt(x);
            t[j][k]=nume;
```

since k is always 1, you will only fill in one of the row/column in your 2d array.

Conclusion. 
print statements are doing no magic.

The code is doing what it is supposed to do.

Think about what you are attempting to do and print out the values of variables to confirm the behaviour as you code.

I am pretty sure that you are attempting to fill the 2d array with numbers and the problem lies with the condition over k but since I do not really know what you are trying to do, I cant be 100% sure.

**Edit**

[image: command line]

Comment: for(int k=1;k<=j;k++)
i know its strange, but the code works with the print statements, but not without them

Comment: I deleted the print statements and ran the code.. It did what I expected it to do. For your input it does not exit but it does read in all the lines.

Comment: this is what I'm getting when I run it without the print statements:
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at monkie.main(monkie.java:36)

its pretty much saying that I'm trying to parse a blank string...

Comment: fair enough.. that is because you are trying to read a total of 10 lines however your input is only 6 lines long. I am guessing there is an empty line at the end of your input which would give a blank line at line 7 of your code. then at line 8 you will try to convert an empty string to an integer.. which is not possible hence the exception. As mentioned before think about what you are attempting to do and examine the variables as the code progresses.

Comment: technically there is never a blank line, since I'm inputting the data. the error occurs after inputting 1(instead of 2), then 4.ie the first two lines of data

Comment: i removed the print statements .. ran : 1\n 4\n 7\n 7\n 7\n 7\n and it worked fine for me

Comment: I have added my output to the answer above

Comment: i am entering 1\n 4\n and then the code terminates and the error message is displayed

Comment: Okay guys, thank you for all your patience and assistance, i switched compiler and the code works perfectly.

Comment: haha.. funny compiler.. which one were you using.. out of pure curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

- Okay first of all, **never** use `StringTokenizer`, as it is deprecated.
- Secondly, arrays are zero indexed. So use `for (i = 0, i < size; i++)` not `i=1` and `i <= size`. I'm going to guess your last programming language was Visual Basic.

  - Your array is too big for the size of your input data. Use `new int[n][n]` with the above zero indexing.
- Your two dimensional array is going to go out of scope as soon as you iterate over the for loop again.
- If you are going to use `readLine`, you will be a lot better off with [`String.split(" ")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

If you can clarify more about what the input format needs to be and the required output, I can help you to read it better.

Comment: Why is StringTokenizer deprecated? I do not see it in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Nick Name

Given your data set, here's how you're reading the input...

<strike>2</strike> ← `line 3` 
<strike>4</strike> ← `line 7` 
<strike>7</strike> ← `line 12`  after this line, you try to tokenize x (which contains only `"7"`), but then you break
6 4                     out of the `k` loop to read the rest of your input (in a really weird way)   
2 5 10         
9 8 12 2

I'm just curious if you are supposed to save the tokens in `[row][cols]` on that `t[][]` array!

```
 1 InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
 2  BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(isr);
 3  String x=in.readLine();
 4  int numcase=Integer.parseInt(x);
 5  for(int i=1;i<=numcase;i++){
 6      System.out.println("");
 7      x=in.readLine();
 8      int n=Integer.parseInt(x);
 9      int[][]t=new int[n+1][n+1];
10      for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
11          System.out.println();
12          x=in.readLine();
14          StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(x);
15          for(int k=1;k<=1;k++){
16              x=st.nextToken();
17              int nume=Integer.parseInt(x);
18              t[j][k]=nume;
19          }
20      }
21
```

Comment: yes, remember, I'm storing it as it is read, as it is, it works, but if i remove the System.out.println statements, it will not read the input.Thats the real problem.

Remember also, "7" has one token so in that line, I only read one token.

the first number is the number of cases, the second the number of rows that contain the data thereafter and the following rows contain the data so I know exactly how many integers there are per line.the tokenizer works fine.